# Can not insert data into mysql database with php

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I am having trouble inserting data to my table via PHP.  The "cc_connect.php" is the file that connects the database. The form is there but when I submit it, no data is added to my table.  I've followed several tutorials and matched their methods without success.  Is something not set up in my db?

the function $dbcon is associated with my connection

```
<form method="post" action="cc_registration.php">
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true" />

    First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name" />
    Last Name: <input type="text" name="last_name" />

<br />
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
```

```
  <?php

   if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

   include ('cc_connect.php');

   if (!$dbcon) {

   die("Can not Connect: " . mysql_error());

}

   mysql_select_db("cooperstown",$dbcon);

$sql = "INSERT INTO cobra_registration (first_name,last_name) VALUES ('$_POST[first_name]', '$_POST[last_name]')";

mysql_query($sql,$dbcon);



mysql_close($dbcon);

}

  ?>
```

Comment: so what values are you inserting?

Comment: $sql = "INSERT INTO cobra_registration (first_name,last_name) VALUES --- You haven't sent any values...

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, but this is wide open to SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: ok, VALUES? where are the values you passing to the statement?, needs to be something like this, VALUES( value i am trying to pass, value i am trying to pass), also please go read about sql injection and try to prevent it in your code

Comment: the values are inserted from the form 'first_name', 'last_name'...  for some reason, if I change the "if(isset($_POST['submit']));" to "if($_POST);", I can add information.  not sure why that is.

Comment: `$_POST[first_name]` is invalid, you need single quotes around `first_name`, same for last.  Turn on your error reporting and you should see warnings and errors with that line.  Try `INSERT INTO cobra_registration (first_name,last_name) VALUES ('" . $_POST['first_name'] ."', '".$_POST['last_name']."')`.  Again though, you should be sanitizing those `post` variables prior to use, otherwise [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com) will get you.

Comment: @MatthewJohnson You're right about sql injection but you're wrong about "$POST[first_name]" being invalid. Have a look at the examples of http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.donts

Comment: @VMai The very first paragraph of the page you link to explains why omitting the quotes is wrong.

Comment: You don't read enough: `// The following is okay, as it's inside a string. Constants are not looked for
// within strings, so no E_NOTICE occurs here
print "Hello $arr[fruit]";      // Hello apple`

Comment: Please try to find a tutorial that at least talks about **error handling**. It's amazing how terrible those learning texts seem to be.

Answer (score 3):

`$_POST['submit']` is never set because you are passing `submitted`.

change:

```
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true" />
```

to:

```
<input type="hidden" name="submit" value="true" />
```

As a side note your current query can easily be hacked. Use Prepared statements instead like PDO or MysQLi, here is an example in PDO:

```
$fName = isset($_POST['first_name']) ? $_POST['first_name'] : '';
$lName = isset($_POST['last_name']) ? $_POST['last_name'] : '';

if ($fName && $lName) {
   $stmt = $db->prepare('
      INSERT INTO cobra_registration (first_name,last_name) 
      VALUES (:fname, :lname)
   ');

   $stmt->bindParam(':fname', $fName, PDO::PARAM_STR);
   $stmt->bindParam(':lname', $lName, PDO::PARAM_STR);

   $res = $stmt->execute();

   if ($res) {
      echo 'Success';
   } else {
      echo 'Failure';
   }
}
```

Comment: I missed the `submitted`, good catch!  However, he should be getting errors with that insert statement. +1

Comment: good grief!!!  thanks.  changed the isset to isset($_Post['submitted'] and it is working!!!

Comment: @jd5 If it solved your problem, please mark it as answer. Then this question will be off the "Unanswered question" list.

Answer (score 2):

The mysql_* functions are deprecated, and should no longer be used.  Look into [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

**IMPORTANT NOTE**

This is WIDE open to [SQL Injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).  You should use prepared statements to protect against such attacks.

GGio nailed his answer, it was the `submitted`, but checking for `submit`.  He also provided a PDO example, so I'll demonstrate the same thing in mysqli:

```
$firstName = isset($_POST['first_name']) ? $_POST['first_name'] : '';
$lastName = isset($_POST['last_name']) ? $_POST['last_name'] : '';

if ($firstName && $lastName) {
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO cobra_registration (first_name,last_name) 
  VALUES (?, ?)"); 
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $firstName, $lastName);
    $stmt->execute();  

}
```

Comment: @VMai His version is missing the single quote around the post variable name.  He has `$_POST[first_name]`, whereas it should be `$_POST['first_name'],  GGio has it though, the `submitted` isn't checked correctly.

Comment: Inside of double quotes you don't have to quote a string as key of an array: `"$_POST[first_name]"` is perfectly valid PHP, even if I don't use this.

Comment: So it is!  Just got through testing that, thanks for teaching me something new!  I'll be deleting the answer shortly.

Comment: Edit your answer. I see no need to delete it. The most important part holds true: "This is WIDE open to SQL Injection attacks ...". This should be repeated as often as possible, if such code appears. And learning by answering and getting corrected is great. Especially by testing by yourself and not believing everything any other said.

Comment: @VMai Good point.  I added links to the `mysqli` and `pdo` docs, and a link to explain injection attacks.  Also added an example using `mysqli` and prepared statements, to augment GGio's PDO example.

Comment: I saw it, remove my first comment that wasn't relevant anymore and gave you +1. You both deserved it.

Comment: My form will eventually have many more inputs to be filled in.  Would I need to do what is show above to all of them? 
FOR EXAMPLE:
$firstName = isset($_POST['first_name']) ? $_POST['first_name'] : '';
$lastName = isset($_POST['last_name']) ? $_POST['last_name'] : '';
$address = isset($_POST['address']) ? $_POST['address'] : '';

if ($firstName && $lastName && $address) {
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO cobra_registration (first_name,last_name,address) 
  VALUES (?, ?)"); 
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $firstName, $lastName, $address);
    $stmt->execute();  
}

Comment: @jd5 The `$lastName = isset($_POST['last_name']) ? $_POST['last_name'] : '';` just checks to makes sure the `post` variable is set prior to assigning it, and prevents an error if it isn't set.  Your example query would need an additional `?`, since you would be inserting an additional variable.  Also, the `bind_param` would need an additional `s`, since you're inserting an additional string.  If you were inserting an integer you would add an `i` to the `bind_param`. More info can found in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).

Comment: @MatthewJohnson Thanks for the link.  I have gone through and added all the variables (along with the "?" and "s" or "i" where applicable and I am getting a syntax error on the last line
    $stmt->execute();

Comment: $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO cobra_registration (first_name,last_name,street,city,state,zip,home_phone,email,birth_month,birth_day,birth_year,grade,school,tryout_date,guard1_first_name,guard1_last_name,guard1_email,guard1_phone,guard1_cell,guard2_first_name,guard2_last_name,guard2_email,guard2_phone,guard2_cell) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

Comment: $stmt->bind_param("sssssiisiiiisssssiisssii", $first_name, $last_name, $street, $city, $state, $zip, $home_phone, $email, $birth_month, $birth_day, $birth_year, $grade, $school, $tryout_date, $guard1_first_name, $guard1_last_name, $guard1_email, $guard1_phone, $guard1_cell, $guard2_first_name, $guard2_last_name, $guard2_email, $guard2_phone, $guard2_cell)
 $stmt->execute();
}

Comment: beginning of "if" statement:
if ($first_name && $last_name && $street && $city && $state && $zip && $home_phone && $email && $birth_month && $birth_day && $birth_year && $grade && $school && $tryout_date && $guard1_first_name && $guard1_last_name && $guard1_email && $guard1_phone && $guard1_cell && $guard2_first_name && $guard2_last_name && $guard2_email && $guard2_phone && $guard2_cell) {

Comment: Might start a new question, since it's hard to read the code in comments.  Looking at the insert statement though, it looks like there is a mismatch in the number of fields and `?`.

Comment: @MatthewJohnson I have posted a new question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24703020/avoiding-sql-injection-attack]