# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$stmt' (T_VARIABLE)

Tags: php

I'm trying to avoid an SQL injection attack and thanks to @Matthew Johnson, I'm nearly there ( I think ).

Getting a syntax error on the "$stmt->execture();" line:

> ```
> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$stmt' (T_VARIABLE)
> ```

I have 24 fields and there are 24 "?" and "s" or "i" so I don't think there is a mismatch.

```
 <?php

 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

 include ('cc_connect.php');

 if (!$dbcon) {
die("Can not Connect: " . mysql_error());

}

mysql_select_db("cooperstown",$dbcon);

$first_name = isset($_POST['first_name']) ? $_POST['first_name'] : '';
$last_name = isset($_POST['last_name']) ? $_POST['last_name'] : '';
$street = isset($_POST['street']) ? $_POST['street'] : '';
$city = isset($_POST['city']) ? $_POST['city'] : '';
$state = isset($_POST['state']) ? $_POST['state'] : '';
$zip = isset($_POST['zip']) ? $_POST['zip'] : '';
$home_phone = isset($_POST['home_phone']) ? $_POST['home_phone'] : '';
$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
$birth_month = isset($_POST['birth_month']) ? $_POST['birth_month'] : '';
$birth_day = isset($_POST['birth_day']) ? $_POST['birth_day'] : '';
$birth_year = isset($_POST['birth_year']) ? $_POST['birth_year'] : '';
$grade = isset($_POST['grade']) ? $_POST['grade'] : '';
$school = isset($_POST['school']) ? $_POST['school'] : '';
$tryout_date = isset($_POST['tryout_date']) ? $_POST['tryout_date'] : '';
$guard1_first_name = isset($_POST['guard1_first_name']) ? $_POST['guard1_first_name'] : '';
$guard1_last_name = isset($_POST['guard1_last_name']) ? $_POST['guard1_last_name'] : '';
$guard1_email = isset($_POST['guard1_email']) ? $_POST['guard1_email'] : '';
$guard1_phone = isset($_POST['guard1_phone']) ? $_POST['guard1_phone'] : '';
$guard1_cell = isset($_POST['guard1_cell']) ? $_POST['guard1_cell'] : '';
$guard2_first_name = isset($_POST['guard2_first_name']) ? $_POST['guard2_first_name'] : '';
$guard2_last_name = isset($_POST['guard2_last_name']) ? $_POST['guard2_last_name'] : '';
$guard2_email = isset($_POST['guard2_email']) ? $_POST['guard2_email'] : '';
$guard2_phone = isset($_POST['guard2_phone']) ? $_POST['guard2_phone'] : '';
$guard2_cell = isset($_POST['guard2_cell']) ? $_POST['guard2_cell'] : '';


if ($first_name && $last_name && $street && $city && $state && $zip && $home_phone && $email && $birth_month && $birth_day && $birth_year && $grade && $school && $tryout_date && $guard1_first_name && $guard1_last_name && $guard1_email && $guard1_phone && $guard1_cell && $guard2_first_name && $guard2_last_name && $guard2_email && $guard2_phone && $guard2_cell) {

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO cobra_registration (first_name,last_name,street,city,state,zip,home_phone,email,birth_month,birth_day,birth_year,grade,school,tryout_date,guard1_first_name,guard1_last_name,guard1_email,guard1_phone,guard1_cell,guard2_first_name,guard2_last_name,guard2_email,guard2_phone,guard2_cell) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sssssiisiiiisssssiisssii", $first_name, $last_name, $street, $city, $state, $zip, $home_phone, $email, $birth_month, $birth_day, $birth_year, $grade, $school, $tryout_date, $guard1_first_name, $guard1_last_name, $guard1_email, $guard1_phone, $guard1_cell, $guard2_first_name, $guard2_last_name, $guard2_email, $guard2_phone, $guard2_cell)
$stmt->execute();
}


}

?>
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Is "syntax error" the complete information provided by the DBMS?

Comment: Have you heard of `;`

Comment: Cool, the error message was fake. I've edited the question to add the actual message so at least others who google here in the future don't get confused. (Of course, Stack Overflow is not an animal traction spell checker so the question is off-topic.)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a semi-colon at the end of the line.
Replace:

```
$stmt->bind_param("sssssiisiiiisssssiisssii", $first_name, $last_name, $street, $city, $state, $zip, $home_phone, $email, $birth_month, $birth_day, $birth_year, $grade, $school, $tryout_date, $guard1_first_name, $guard1_last_name, $guard1_email, $guard1_phone, $guard1_cell, $guard2_first_name, $guard2_last_name, $guard2_email, $guard2_phone, $guard2_cell)
```

With:

```
$stmt->bind_param("sssssiisiiiisssssiisssii", $first_name, $last_name, $street, $city, $state, $zip, $home_phone, $email, $birth_month, $birth_day, $birth_year, $grade, $school, $tryout_date, $guard1_first_name, $guard1_last_name, $guard1_email, $guard1_phone, $guard1_cell, $guard2_first_name, $guard2_last_name, $guard2_email, $guard2_phone, $guard2_cell);
```

Comment: Grrr... it was that ; ! thanks!!!

Comment: So the syntax error is gone but the data is not inserting into the table when it is submitted.  Any help is appreciated!